# Concurrent HashMap keeps giving wrong output with AtomicInteger

Tags: java

I'm trying to increment a value in an object within a `ConcurrentHashMap` but it keeps giving the output that is not expected. I have also tried using the `AtomicInteger` but its the same.
The expected output is that `John` and `Doe` each have 100 count. However, this doesn't happen. What seems to be the problem. This works fine without the `Data` object as a value.

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

```
public class Data {

    private AtomicInteger count;

    public Data() {
    }

    public Data(AtomicInteger count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public AtomicInteger getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = new AtomicInteger(count);
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
public class TestCmapwithobejct {

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Data> cmap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private static void process() {
        for(String data: cmap.keySet()) {
            for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
                Data value = cmap.get(data);
                value.setCount(value.getCount().incrementAndGet());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cmap.put("John", new Data(new AtomicInteger()));
        cmap.put("Doe", new Data(new AtomicInteger()));

        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        ex.submit(TestCmapwithobejct::process);
        ex.submit(TestCmapwithobejct::process);
        ex.shutdown();

        cmap.keySet().forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println(x +":"+ cmap.get(x).getCount());
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that `value.setCount(value.getCount().incrementAndGet());` is not thread-safe. Instead of this use the solution that gudok proposes - that one **is** thread-safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you call `setCount()`, you are creating new `AtomicInteger`. You should not do this. Replace `value.setCount(value.getCount().incrementAndGet());` with just `value.getCount().incrementAndGet()`.